# RPM upgrade database

Tags: rpm

I have a system where I have to find a process on how to migrate from rpm 4.6.0-rc1 (2009) rpm to 4.11.3 (2014). The problem is, that executing the new rpm on the system of the old one, will give me errors about unrecognized db options

> error: unrecognized db option: "hash" ignored.

as well as

> db5 error(-30969) from dbenv->open: BDB0091 DB_VERSION_MISMATCH: Database environment version mismatch

using

```
rpm --rebuilddb
```

or

```
rpm --initdb
```

will somehow do what I want, but also the unrecognized db options will persist.
I though about completely wiping the db and rebuilding it from scratch which does not seem to work?

My question therefore is - **Is it somehow possible to completely rebuild the database or is there a way to upgrade it?**

When I clear the database (remove files) and use `--initdb` or `--rebuilddb`, the output of package query's will always be empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, it seems that there is absolutely no way to upgrade rpm databases this way.
While complete cleaning and rebuilding is not possible (it will no recognize any package at all), only rebuilding based on the current packages keeps those faulty db options. 
I will not manually change that db so I will stay with that